# Access the same Entity via various attributes in DynamoDB

Tags: database-design, dynamodb, single-table-design

I'll begin by saying I am new to DynamoDB and the world of NoSQL in general. I have a `patient` entity and I am storing it in a DynamoDB table.

My access patterns for the `patient` entity are:

1. Get patient by id
2. Get patient by first name
3. Get patient by last name
4. Get patient by date of birth
5. Get patient by post code

How can I achieve this with my DynamoDB table? Right now, the basic model I've put together is:

[image: dynobase screenshot]

I'm still in the data modelling phase, so I can ditch that make as many changes as I want.

Comment: Why DynamoDB when you have what appears to be a well-defined relational object with standard use cases?

Comment: Why not DynamoDB? Advocates of DynamoDB constantly remind us that DynamoDB can handle well defined relationships? But to answer your question, cause the app I’m building is fully serverless, and I want to learn DynamoDB modelling

Comment: And RDBMS can handle not so well defined and denormalized data models, doesn't mean it's necessarily the right tool for the right job. But I'm just asking anyway to understand what problem you're trying to solve with it. If it's for your own learning experience then power to ya.